# $get property for a $http/$resource service?

Tags: angularjs

Trying to figure out what is going on in this code - I have a `$resource` service which I am using to request data from Rails backend, something like:

```
$scope.my_objects = my_objects_results.get(.... );
```

In the view, I have an `ng-repeat` which does an `my_object in my_objects` and in a directive for `my_object` there is a line of code like:

```
 my_object.$get(successCallback);
```

I appears that this code is calling a simple http get for `my_object`. But I guess I am not sure why? All the documentation I read is that the $get is the constructor function for a service. But I am having trouble finding documentation on what the $get property is for $resource (or $http?) ... something that would confirm what I am observing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered in the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the documentation that explains $get w/r/t to $resource here:

http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/servercalls/resourceservice/

the gist is:

> We can divide the methods in two separate categories:
>   constructor-level methods and instance-level methods. All of them send
>   and receive JSON objects, but the main distinction is that the
>   constructor-level ones are available in the object returned by the
>   $resource constructor while the instance-level methods are available
>   in any instance of resource, that is an instance returned by the
>   server or an instance created on the client with the new keyword on
>   the object returned by the $resource constructor.

and

> Every Resource instance has the basic $get, $query, $save and $delete
>   methods. They're equivalent to their constructor-level counterparts in
>   their meaning, but there are some differences.

I think this is basically on the main angular documentation as well, but it was less obvious.